# add service reference failed in WCF

Tags: wcf

My solution is having 3 projects , 1 for linq and .dbml , 1 website and 1 WCF services . WCF services project has many WCF services in it, each WCF is having separate Interface and class file. I added one more WCF in in as per the project requirement. the WCF build and deployed successfully, I set the WCF project as the start-up project the run the solution then it says that service is started.

I tried to add the reference of this WCF service in the WebSite, the discover button shows the newly added WCF in the list of services available within the solution.

I found my service, gave a suitable name and added, then the error message appeared on the bottom left corner of the window "Add Service reference failed"

No other error or detailed message is shown.

Please help!

This is the App.Config of service project

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="WCFSrv.ServiceBehavior"
    name="WCFSrv.SalesMIReportService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCFSrv.IReportDataProvider">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFSrv/SalesMIReportService/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>



<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WCFSrv.ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />

    </behavior>

  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>




<bindings>

  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IDriverSalesService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
        openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
        bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
        allowCookies="false">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
          maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
          enabled="false" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Below is the complete App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name=Global.Diagnostics.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection="", System="", Version="2.0.0.0", Culture="neutral", PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false="""/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="databaseServer" value="DBSERVER\DEV1P1"/>
    <add key="EventLogSource" value=""/>
    <add key="EventLogName" value=""/>
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value=""/>
    <add key="DocumentLocation" value="X:\\\Client\Web\Site\pdf"/>
    <add key="Proxy" value="172.22.53.35"/>
    <add key="COMServiceLocatorUrl" value="http://iisdbhxv04/COMServiceLocator/COMServiceLocator.asmx"/>

    <!--***********************************************
       The AppSetting Keys used to EPYX CodeVehicleService
    ***************************************************-->
    <!--Move properties to LIA-->
    <!--Ids for the service booking components-->
    <add key="1LinkServiceId" value="1" />
    <add key="connectServiceId" value="2" />
    <!--Proxy Server Settings (outbound security credentials)-->
    <add key="liveServer" value="false" />
    <add key="proxyServer" value="http://172.22.55.35:80" />

    <!--The type of Code booking that will be done. The value of this setting can be either "Connect" or "Downtime"-->
    <!--<add key="CodeBooking" value="Connect"/>-->
    <add key="CodeBooking" value="Downtime" />
    <!--Test credentials for Code Booking -->
    <add key="CodeOriginatorId" value="8" />
    <add key="CodePassword" value="XMLTEST" />
    <!--Test Components -->
    <add key="CodeNetworkBookingService" value="https://www.1link.com/uk/test-hn/site/OperatorIntegration.asmx" />


  </appSettings>

  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Warning, Error" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>

    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="xml" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\temp\Traces_.svclog"/>
    </sharedListeners>

  </system.diagnostics>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri=""/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"/>
    </diagnostics>
    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="ServiceErrorHandler" type="Global.ServiceModel.ServiceErrorHandlerBehaviorExtensionElement", Temp.Global.ServiceModel="", Version="1.0.0.0", Culture="neutral", PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>

    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WCFSrv.ServiceBehavior"
        name="WCFSrv.Service">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCFSrv.ICommon">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFSrv/Service/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>

      <service behaviorConfiguration="WCFSrv.ServiceBehavior"
        name="WCFSrv.SalesMIPublicationService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCFSrv.IPublicationDataProvider">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFSrv/SalesMIPublicationService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>

      <service behaviorConfiguration="WCFSrv.ServiceBehavior"
        name="WCFSrv.CodeBookingService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCFSrv.ICodeBooking">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFSrv/CodeBookingService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="LargeMessageBehavior" name="WCFSrv.QuoteService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCFSrv.IQuote">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" behaviorConfiguration="" binding="mexHttpBinding"
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFSrv/QuoteService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WCFSrv.ServiceBehavior"
        name="WCFSrv.LcvRateService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="QuoteEndpointBehaviour"
          binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCFSrv.ILcvRate">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" behaviorConfiguration="" binding="mexHttpBinding"
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFSrv/LcvRateService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="LargeMessageBehavior" name="WCFSrv.AlertsService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCFSrv.IAlerts">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" behaviorConfiguration="" binding="mexHttpBinding"
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFSrv/AlertsService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WCFSrv.ServiceBehavior"
        name="WCFSrv.PlacementService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCFSrv.IPlacement">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFSrv/PlacementService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WCFSrv.ServiceBehavior"
        name="WCFSrv.PublicationService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCFSrv.IPublication">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFSrv/PublicationService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WCFSrv.ServiceBehavior"
        name="WCFSrv.AccessService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCFSrv.IAccess">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFSrv/AccessService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WCFSrv.ServiceBehavior"
        name="WCFSrv.ServicesService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCFSrv.IServices">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFSrv/ServicesService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WCFSrv.ServiceBehavior"
        name="WCFSrv.RoadService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCFSrv.IRoadServices">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFSrv/RoadService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WCFSrv.ServiceBehavior"
        name="WCFSrv.AverageLoggerService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCFSrv.IAverageLogger" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFSrv/AverageLoggerService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WCFSrv.ServiceBehavior"
        name="WCFSrv.DriverCertificationService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCFSrv.IDriverCertification" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFSrv/DriverCertificationService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WCFSrv.ServiceBehavior"
        name="WCFSrv.ImscanService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCFSrv.IImscanServices" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFSrv/ImscanService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WCFSrv.ServiceBehavior"
        name="WCFSrv.NominationService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCFSrv.INomination" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFSrv/NominationService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WCFSrv.ServiceBehavior"
        name="WCFSrv.UserRegistrationService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCFSrv.IUserRegistration" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFSrv/UserRegistrationService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service name="WCFSrv.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCFSrv.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFSrv/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="LargeMessageBehavior" name="WCFSrv.CvAccessoryService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCFSrv.ICvAccessory">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFSrv/CvAccessoryService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service name="WCFSrv.PoolFleetManagementService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCFSrv.IPoolFleetManagementService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFSrv/PoolFleetManagementService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WCFSrv.ServiceBehavior"
        name="WCFSrv.ServiceFormsService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCFSrv.IServiceFormService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFSrv/ServiceFormsService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WCFSrv.ServiceBehavior"
        name="WCFSrv.DriverSalesService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCFSrv.IDriverSalesService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFSrv/DriverSalesService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="QuoteEndpointBehaviour">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="655360" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WCFSrv.ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />

        </behavior>
        <behavior name="LargeMessageBehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />

        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MotorServiceSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
          receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildMotord"
          maxBufferSize="655366" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="655366"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IDriverSalesService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
            openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
            bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildMotord"
            maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
            allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession Placemented="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
              enabled="false" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://172.22.191.44/MotorService/MotorService.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MotorServiceSoap" contract="Motor.MotorServiceSoap" name="MotorServiceSoap"/>
      <endpoint address="http://iisdbhxv02.prod.ltsbafd.net//CONNECT/LIVECONTRACTS/DRIVERSALES/DriverSalesService.svc"
          binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IDriverSalesService"
          contract="DriverSalesSrv.IDriverSalesService" name="WSHttpBinding_IDriverSalesService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <applicationSettings>
    <Temp.Global.Diagnostics.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="Folder" serializeAs="String">
        <value>C:\WebServices\WebServiceUsageLogs</value>
      </setting>
    </Temp.Global.Diagnostics.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=""NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You said the WCF services project has many WCF services in it. However, the config file you listed has only one. Would you list the whole content at least those within ServiceModel?

Comment: complete app config posted

Comment: Have you run the service at least once in IDE so IIS Express is hosting the service?

Comment: Yes, on running service the WCF Service Host window pops up and says service started

Comment: In WCF test client I Tested the service, I send Request and get the required response.

Comment: Apparently you are not using service activation through config, so do you have svc files in the root directory of the Website hosted by IIS?

Comment: ohh... thats correct... I added the .svc file in the root directory of website and its done now.. Thanks a ton